# Adding and removing listeners continually

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I add a listener when user goes to a certain page. If the user leaves the page, I remove the listener. I'm doing this because I don't want to download the updates that the user doesn't need anymore. Can we say this is a good practice? User can go back and forth between the pages and it will cause several listeners to be added and removed continually. What are the potential issues from the aspect of **performance** and **cost**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're describing, there will be no negative impact on performance and cost.  Adding and removing listeners is cheap.  If you are only doing it during page navigation, that is not actually very fast at all, by any standard.